# When do you use warning(msg)?

Tags: r

I am a little confused about the reason why R has `warning(msg)`. It seems it doesn't really cause anything to happen during code execution except store some messages in `warnings()` that no one ever really looks at.

Maybe I am using it wrong. Maybe I am misunderstanding its purpose. No other language I used has a warning exception, most just have an exception (I guess thie equates to an `error(msg)` in R). Is `warning(msg)` an exception that I just ignore, then what's the point of it?

Maybe someone has a good explanation of when you SHOULD use a `warning(msg)`? or what it was intended to be used for?

Comment: If the minimal threshold of refuting your point is a single argument, a vital application of `warning()` would be that results of your function might be incorrect if certain assumptions are not met (which couldn't be detected by the function).

Comment: why the negative votes?

Comment: @jay.sf if a function can't guarantee a correct result it should throw an exception. I can catch the exception and deal with it (maybe revise assumptions, etc.). `warnings(msg)` is just too easy to miss. It's like a function saying sum(2,2)=5 so throw a warning() saying the result is probably incorrect and then just continue the regression...

Comment: In response to : **It seems it doesn't really cause anything to happen during code execution except store some messages in warnings() that no one ever really looks at.**, try running this: `why_warning<-function(x){
  if(is.numeric(x)){
    warning("x must be a string")
  }
  print(x)
};
why_warning(2)`

Comment: In short, `warning` is intended to acknowledge that there are problems but they have been "ignored" and a result returned. This is particularly useful for numerical computations.

Comment: @NelsonGon - that is a good example. Never seen it used like that... Not sure how it knew that x is invalid when you tried to use it in a print(x) statement... You should put that as an answer with some explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand it, `warning()` is an alternative to `message()` not necessarily to `stop()` which causes an error. In a warning a user is *informed* that something is not as expected but it is left to the user to decide if the problem is severe and if they want to re-write their code.

The main difference between `message()` and `warning()` is that a warning message will lead with `Warning message:` and that `R` keeps track if the latter one occurs. You can choose for yourself if you want your code to completely stop on any warning as well by setting

```
options(warn = 2)
```

One usage I can think of is to warn the user that a function s/he is using will be deprecated soon.Many users will choose run the code anyway and fix it later on when they have time. But they definitely know now there is a problem in the future.

Another use case would be to make the user aware of a problem that was fixed internally. In this case the user should know that the function did more than the user asked for, in case the fix is not what they were trying to do. An example from `dplyr` would be this:

```
> a <- data.frame(x = c("p", "q", NA), y = c(1, 2, 3), stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
> b <- data.frame(x = c("p", "q", "r"), z = c(4, 5, 6), stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
> res <- inner_join(a, b, "x")
Warning message:
Column `x` joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector
```

This could mean there is a severe issue or absolutely nothing, depending on your use case.

You could choose to stop the function if you prefer that users get it right on their own. And in fact [some people advocate for that principle](https://www.r-bloggers.com/a-warning-about-warning/). I usually try to make my packages as user-friendly as possible so people don't have to struggle with an error they don't understand. At the same time I want to inform them they might have made a common mistake could opt to fix it if it was not what they intended to do.

Answer (score 3):

In response to : It seems it doesn't really cause anything to happen during code execution except store some messages in warnings() that no one ever really looks at., try running this:

```
 why_warning<-function(x){ 
    if(is.numeric(x)){ 
       warning("x must be a string")
    } 
    print(x)
 }
```

Running this with:

```
why_warning(2)
```

We get:

```
[1] 2
Warning message:
In why_warning(2) : x must be a string
```

In short, warning is intended to acknowledge that there are problems but they have been "ignored" and a result returned. This is particularly useful for numerical computations.

Compare this to the function below:

```
why_warning<-function(x){
  stopifnot(is.character(x))

  print(x)
}
```

The above will not "return" any value but rather stop and throw the error:

```
Error in why_warning(2) : is.character(x) is not TRUE
```

Therefore, depending on the goal of the function, a warning may be just that: a warning. However, it may mean that whatever results one obtains are erroneous.

You can find more details on `warning` under: `?warning`.